# density of 2 bivariate gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, covariance

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are bi-variate Gaussian with equal mean and variance. 
how do i find the density of & $y = A_1X_1 + B_1X_2$.? I think I should use correlation co-efficient here which i assume as $p$. but cant find a way really. any suggestion plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a bivariate normal distribution, one can specify the two means, the two variances, and the covariance.  You haven't said anything about the covariance.  You would have
$$
\operatorname{var}(A_1X_1+B_1X_2) = A_1^2\operatorname{var}(X_1) + B_1^2\operatorname{var}(X_2) + 2A_1B_2\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2).
$$
The expected value of $A_1X_1+B_1X_2$ is easier to find than that.  Once you've to the variance and expected value, do you know how to go from there to the density?

Comment: hi, i think, u are talking about this formula: $Var(X) = Σx^2p − μ^2$ . So, we first calculate variance and expectation of y and then replace it in the equation. I got it, but the question remains is, what should I do with $Σx^2$? just keep it or it can expressed by way of mean and variance of these variables?

Comment: also, the density of $y=A1X1+B1X2$ will also be Gaussian. so how i show that if i use this formula: $Var(X)=Σx2p−μ2$??

Comment: I wasn't using that formula at all.  As for showing that it's Gaussian, that's actually the definition of bivariate Gaussian: A pair $(X_1,X_2)$ has a bivariate Gaussian distribution precisely if every linear combination of it has a univariate Gaussian distribution.

Comment: thanks for your help. really appreciate it. .i have got the expectation too. but i still could not figure out how i can find the "distribution of y" from variance and expectation of y.

Comment: @chowdhury : Usually for the normal distribution one says which distribution it is by saying it's the normal distribution with a certain mean and variance.  If you need the density, it's $\displaystyle x\mapsto\frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-1}2 \left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2\right)$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are respectively the mean and the variance. ${}\qquad{}$